# "Border" doesn't render the entire width of its container

Tags: css

I am trying to display a list of items within a system.

The list of items allows users to view lots of information per row. Users can add additional columns to this view, making the rows longer as a result.

I want to be able to scroll both vertically and horizontally through this information. When additional columns are added, I want to be able to scroll horizontally to view the new information.

[image]

The scrolling works as I would expect. However, each of these rows has a border underneath it. Strangely, **the border only expands to the width of the browser**. When I scroll horizontally, the border is cut off:

[image]

Here is a basic example of my code to demonstrate it in action:

```html
<div style="overflow-x: scroll;">
  <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid red; display: flex;">
    <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; ">Item Name</div>
    <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; ">Item Owner</div>
    <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; ">Date Created</div>
    <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; ">Additional Information</div>
    <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; ">Additional Metadata</div>
    <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; "><button>A Button</button></div>
    <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; "><button>A Button</button></div>
    <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; "><button>A Button</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question says you are using CSS grid, yet your code example uses `display: flex`.

Comment: You're right, I'll change that. I thought it added additional context but I can see how it's unrelated and potentially confusing!

Comment: The border *does* render the entire width of the element you place it on. By default, `div` elements stretch to 100% of their parent's width, so in your case you have overflowing items in it. You will see that immediately if you add `overflow: hidden` on the flex container.

Comment: inline-flex instead of flex + min-width:100%

Answer (score 3):

You could add  `width: max-content` to the intermediate `div` so it will wrap all its inner content (which is overflowing in your example).

```html
<div style="overflow-x: scroll;">
    <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid red; display: flex; width: max-content">
        <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; ">Item Name</div>          
        <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; ">Item Owner</div>          
        <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; ">Date Created</div>          
        <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; ">Additional Information</div>          
        <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; ">Additional Metadata</div>       
        <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; "><button>A Button</button></div>       
        <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; "><button>A Button</button></div>       
        <div style="padding: 15px; white-space: nowrap; "><button>A Button</button></div>       
    </div>
                    
</div>
```